# Comparing to current date time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, ractivejs

I'm trying to mark up my first page with Ractive. I need to have an if expression that compares a momentjs property from my data object (EndDateTime) to the current date time. Here is what I tried:

```
{{#if EndDateTime.isAfter(moment()) }}
```

It doesn't work. If I change it to EndDateTime.isAfter(StartDateTime) (where StartDateTime is another moment object) it works.

Could you please help me understand why comparison to moment() doesn' work and how can I compare to the current date time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moment` needs to be defined in your data if it isn't already:

```
data: {
    moment: moment,
    ... //other data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

martypdx's answer probably explains why your current code doesn't work, but you can also take advantage of the fact that the `isAfter` function will default to the current time if you pass no arguments.

In other words, the code you gave is equivalent to:

```
{{#if EndDateTime.isAfter() }}
```

[This is in the documentation here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/).